# gparted operation failed after almost 10 hours

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted, disk

Finally after being patient for 10 hours, Gparted came back and performed one of two tasks:

1. It succeeded in resizing a 300 GiB NTFS partition to 270 GiB after moving 270 GiB to the right side.
2. It failed in maximizing the Ubuntu partition from 40 to 70 GiB.

I added that 30 GiB to the Ubuntu partition and repaired the NTFS partition system files after moving all my data in this partition to the other one with the disks utility.

All my work finished under booting my grml-rescueboot ISO file from the hard disk. Is there any advice to perform like tasks like this in easy manner without consuming this much time?

[image: gparted stuck almost 10 hours and finally come back]

Comment: I'd recommend to use Windows tools to edit NTFS partitions. Moving a partition means also moving data, so time needed depends on how full the partition is. Examine beforehand. From my experience, gparted can be painfully slow when doing such tasks. Since you should have backup anyway to avoid risk of data loss, maybe be faster to delete partition and restore data from backup.

Comment: @Nmath thanks for editing my question. the mistake is trying to resize ubuntu partition when it in use because grml-rescueboot ISO file booted from the hard disk not from USB drive. moving big amount of data is the second mistake as mook765 said "gparted can be painfully slow when doing such tasks".

Comment: @mook765 thanks for your recommendations